# Advanced Bootstrap Forms

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, tabular

I have a silly question about Twitter Bootstrap. I want to create a form like this:

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [vertex42.com](https://images.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/expense-reimbursement-form.gif))</sub>

I want this to, so that printing is easy and looks better in paper than the normal forms.

Is there a way of doing this other than using tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The way this is usually done is by using divs as the table rows and columns. Take a look at the bootstrap docs at [getbootstrap.com](http://www.getbootstrap.com), but in general you probably want something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row-sm-6"> First column, first row </div>
    <div class="row-sm-6"> Second column, first row </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="row-sm-4"> First column, second row </div>
    <div class="row-sm-4"> Second column, second row </div>
    <div class="row-sm-4"> Third column, second row </div>
</div>
```

The question is a bit vague too. What exactly are you having trouble with? If you're having trouble with particular styling issues that isnt covered by standard bootstrap classes you should let us know and we can help you figure out those more specifically.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a table, but I'm not sure whether what I did was right or not.

Comment: By the way, I can't place <span>'s inside <td>'s. Is it normal? I want to place some <input>s inside <td>'s. And I want users to input monetary values into there. Like $40. I want to use prepend input thingy of bootstrap. What must I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: Something like this? <div class="form-group">
    <label for="priceInput1">Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="priceInput1" placeholder="Enter $ amnt">
  </div>